# Get height of all children and apply it to parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to calculate the height of a `"height: auto"` div and then apply it to the div. I've done it like this:

```
function center(divName) {
    $(":animated").promise().done(function () {
        var totalHeight = 0;

        $(divName).children().each(function () {
            alert(totalHeight);
            totalHeight += $(this).height();
        });

        $(divName).css("height", totalHeight + "px");
    });
}

center("#frame_01");
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="frame_01">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <h2 id="next_frame_02">Continue</h2>
</div>
```

Notice the `alert(totalHeight);`, im using that to test the script, problem is, the scripts returns the first children with 0px but the second one correctly.

I first thought this would be because it starts to calculate before the animation is complete, therefor not getting height of first children, so I applied `$(":animated").promise().done(function() {` so the script waits for the animation to complete before calculating.

But this didn't solve it, any suggestions why?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

What Im trying to achieve is center a div, but to do that i need the height of the div. This is the CSS:

```
#frame_01 {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

After the height is set with `background-color: red`:

[image]

Comment: I might be missing something as it seems kind-of obvious, but wouldn't that be because `alert(totalHeight);` needs to go _after_ `totalHeight += $(this).height();`?

Comment: how you are animating? via `css3` or jQuery's `.animate()`

Comment: Your making the alert before calculating totalheight, So for first child its showing as 0. Try like this, totalHeight += $(this).height(); alert(totalHeight);

Comment: So, your code returns `68px` - is it incorrect? You probably want to get `marging`s as well?

Comment: Matt: The summed height is still wrong, what Im trying to achieve is center a div, but to do that i need to set a height. Jai: Im using .animate(). Updated my question for better explanation

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a fiddle? There might be other ways to achieve what you seek

Comment: Try this quick solution: `var margs = parseInt($(this).css('margin-top').replace('px', '')) + parseInt($(this).css('margin-bottom').replace('px', ''));
            totalHeight += $(this).height() + margs;`. Or use `outerHeight` instead of 'height()'. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Should `$(":animated").promise().done(function () {` have another the element being animated before it?

Comment: I solved it, check my answer! Thanks anyway for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing `.height()` to `.outerHeight(true)`

Code:

```
function center(divName) {
    $(":animated").promise().done(function () {
        var totalHeight = 0;

        $(divName).children().each(function () {
            alert(totalHeight);
            totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true);
        });

        $(divName).css("height", totalHeight + "px");
    });
}

center("#frame_01");
```